# Ошибка Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime что делать?

Tags: python, pycharm

Помогите пожалуйста, ошибка:[image]

(MacOs)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)